# simple form in JSF not working

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to create a simple form using jsf.
Here's my Java code:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorld {

private String name;
private String message;

public void createMessage() {
    message = "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(){
    message = "Hello, " + name + "!";
}

}
```

this is my home.xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Enter your name" required="true" />
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloWorld.name}" />
    <h:message for="name" />
     <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Say hello" action="#{helloWorld.createMessage}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <br />
       <h:message value="{helloWorld.message}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

when I try to open it in a browser under this address: http://localhost:8080/helloworld/home.jsf
it displays a text "Enter your name", a text box and a button entitled "Say hello" under it. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. Could you please advise, why? I've already compared it with many other examples and they look similar. Any advise will be appreciate as I'm a beginner in this jsf stuff.
If you need some more details, please let me know. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `<h:message value="{helloWorld.message}" />` doesn't belong to anything (and doesn't have a `#`). Try a `<h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.message}" />`.

Comment: this partially resolved the problem but the button still doesn't work.

Comment: I think there's something wrong here:
<h:outputLabel for="name" value="Enter your name" required="true" />
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloWorld.name}" />
 <h:message for="name" />
as there's Error message shown in Eclipse's preview

Comment: Well, works for me. https://github.com/karlnicholas/TestJsfTomcat